# why is my scraper showing 'none' as the output?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


url = 'https://www.flipkart.com'


data = {
    'q': 'laptops'
}

html_code = requests.post(url, data=data).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')

titles = soup.findAll('div', class_='_3wU53n')

for title in titles:
    print(title, end='\n')
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the `titles`? Maybe the `titles` variable is `NoneType`.

Comment: It seems that there does not have a class with id = '_3wU53n' during the requests. Maybe you should try using selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

to_search = 'laptops'
url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q= 
{}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as- 
show=on&as=off'.format(to_search)

html_code = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')

titles = soup.findAll('div', class_='_3wU53n')

for title in titles:
    print(title, end='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check again. Firstly, The url 'https://www.flipkart.com' is actually a 'GET' request and not 'POST'. Secondly, the class: _3wU53n which you have provided is actually not present in the HTML DOM. Have a look in the below screenshot for the 'GET' request and 'Absence of class: _3wU53n' in the HTML DOM.

[image]

[image]